# Ubuntu 21.10 - Touchpad three finger gestures stopped working

Tags: mouse, multi-touch, 21.10

This morning, I started ubuntu (installed alongside windows 11) and 3-finger gestures weren't working and the display feel laggy.
I had installed `Nvidia cuda`, I checked the recent installation in `/var/log/apt/history.log` and removed all recent installation and `autoremove` any leftovers but gestures still not worked.

It happened to me once before and I had to reinstall ubuntu (PAIN!)
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In my laptop, this feature working in Wayland and not working with Xorg.
you can change Xorg to Wayland here:

```
sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Then uncomment

```
WaylandEnable=false
```